# I am getting type if errors Invalid Assignment operator and 'n' cannot be resolved as variable

Tags: java, variables, recursion, compiler-errors, operators

I am getting 2 type of errors 'n' cannot be resolved as var. and         (Syntax error on token ":", invalid AssignmentOperator)
I am currently learning java so if anyone can help me out with this errors it would be a great
Thank you
Here is the code (java)

```
  public class NumbersEg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write a function that takes in a num. and prints it
        //  print first 5 nums. 1 2 3 4 5
        print1(n:1);
    }

    static void print1(int n) {
        System.out.println(n);
        print2(n:2);
    }

    static void print2(int n) {
        System.out.println(n);
        print3(n:3);
    }

    static void print3(int n) {
        System.out.println(n);
        print4(n:4);
        
    }

    static void print4(int n) {
        System.out.println(n);
        print5(n:5);
    }

    static void print5(int n) {
        System.out.println(n);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `n:1`? It looks as though you need to study basic Java syntax.

Comment: The `:` is not an assignment operator, so all those `(n:..)` arguments are invalid. If you want to pass a bare number, just pass the number `1`, `2` etc.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are trying to do something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write a function that takes in a num. and prints it
        //  print first 5 nums. 1 2 3 4 5
        int n = 1;
        print1(n);
    }
```